# SQL Transaction Logs bloating with Replication

Tags: sql, database-replication, database-mirroring

I am trying to setup a replication database that has a lot of read/writes, although the overall database size is about 35gb.

A transactional replication server has been configured, however over a week, the logs bloated to 22GB and slowed the server to a grind.

I managed to stop the replication and the logs from growing and now is stable with the logs at 0.1% of 22gb used (I have not shrunk the overall log size as I did not see the need for this as yet).

- Full backups done nightly with Windows Backup
- Recovery model is SIMPLE
- Runs on RAID10 with 8x SAS 10K drives
- 32GB RAM, Win2008 x64 SP1
- Restricted SQL to utilise only 24GB, thus server holding 75% memory utilisation
- Avg Disk Activity is about 100KB/s and queue length being 0.05 without any replication according to Resource Monitor
- Backup Server is running same OS, 4GB RAM, RAID1 SATA 7.2k 500GB

Question is - what did I do wrong to cause the Transaction logs to continually grow?

If more info is needed, please advise what tool I should use and I can post them accordingly.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I am sorry to hear about this ordeal. I'll star this question, if nobody answers i'll put it under a bounty.

Comment: Thanks for the push - although I figured out a work-around which s settings up a Maintenance Plan to just dump the Logs every 15 minutes. However now I have the issue of the Clients crashing every time they do a report when mirroring or replication is enabled!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to read the transaction logs and investigate operations that cause the growth. For more information check out the [Open LDF file and view LDF file content](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/open-ldf-file-and-view-ldf-file-content/) online article

*Disclaimer: I work as a Product Support Engineer at ApexSQL*

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, what do you see for the 'log_reuse_wait_desc' in sys.databases ( SELECT * FROM sys.databases )

It sounds like the replication engine may be holding on to the transaction logs because the data hasn't been fully replicated yet  - do you have any subscribers that are offline?